# Maven issue while installing Spring project

Tags: spring, maven

Attended Spring Core training recently. When I installed the projects after the course and converted the projects as a Maven project, I get the following error.

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: The repository system is offline but the artifact com.springsource.training.core-spring:parentCoreSpringProject:pom:
 4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT is not available in the local repository. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

I tried adding relative-path too, but it did not help.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.springsource.training.core-spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentCoreSpringProject</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Are you using the STS installer that you got when you attended the training? as this has the parent POM

Comment: Yes, I am using the installer that was part of the training as this has plugins for the projects as well

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear - the pom points to a repository that you don;t have access to.

Either get access, or change the repository it points to.

(maven downloads required dependencies(jar files) from a server and apparently you don't have access to specified server but you can use public servers/repositories instead)